# Insert HTML into python HTML template

Tags: python, html

```
##### CREATE HTML TEMPLATE ######

html_template = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <meta charset = 'UTF-8'>

    <title>SHOPPING OUTLET</title>

  </head>

  <body>

      $items$

  </body>

</html>
"""

def print_invoice():
    # Get the document's title
    title = 'invoice'

    # Replace elements with items(name, img, price) in the HTML template

    html_code = html_template.replace('$items$', '$items$') * count
    html_code = html_code.replace('$items$', '<h1>***TITLE***</h1> <\b> <p><img src = ***IMG***></p> <\b> <p> Our Price:  ***PRICE***</p> <\b>')
    for html_replace in range(count):
        html_code = html_code.replace('***TITLE***', html_names[html_replace])
        html_code = html_code.replace('***IMG***', html_imgs[html_replace])
        html_code = html_code.replace('***PRICE***', html_prices[html_replace])
    # Write the HTML code to a Unicode text file
    html_file = open(title + '.html', 'w', encoding = 'UTF-8')
    html_file.write(html_code)
    html_file.close()
```

So to start I have a tkinter interface that acts as a shopping outlet/interface and this HTML is to generate an invoice of items added to a cart. I created three separate lists for the individual elements of the items selected as I feel it's probably easier to format the HTML with separate lists?

This currently adds the last item pressed to all the HTML blocks that were created. I realize the for loop is currently not doing anything as the html_code.replace is adding the last item selected to all the >>>TITLE<<< etc. sections of the HTML template.

Do I run a for loop that creates one massive string and then simple insert it as a whole block or is it better to add each item individually.

```
for html_replace in range(count):
    html_code = '<h1>' + html_names[html_replace] + '<\h>' etc...
    #Not sure if this will work
```

I had also considered moving the html_code.replace sections into the add_to_cart button press and making the items add individually when the add_to_cart button is pressed.

Am new to coding and just trying to understand the best way to do this. 
I did find some info on using beautiful soup but am unsure if I can use for this (waiting on response from lecturer).

Comment: Also i understand the formatting of the html isnt good at the moment. just trying to get the basics working at this stage.

Comment: Try using an existing templating engine instead of implementing your own. There are good ones out there, for example jinja or mako, but here is a good list of them: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating